# Need advice/suggestion on pthread synchronization (combine the use of condition variable and barrier)

Tags: pthreads, condition-variable, synchronization, barrier

I have the following scenario:

I split one task into several stages, there are several threads in each stage to do the actual work, and the threads of in later stage need to wait for all threads in current stage to complete.

For example:

Thread 1, 2, 3 are doing the work in step one

Thread 4, 5, 6 are doing the work in step two

Thread 7, 8, 9 are doing the step three
...

The threads in each of the step are independent, but they need to wait for the threads in previous step to finish.

Here is how I want to achieve this:

1. In each thread of the current step, wait on the condition that representing that if current step can be started
2. once the current step can be started, all the threads start doing the work, and wait on a barrier for all the threads in this step to finish
3. After all the threads in this step finish, broadcast on the condition variable on which the next step threads are waiting

Does it make sence? Anything obviously wrong here?

I am spoiled by the high level language structures for multi-threading programs, and using the pthread APIs is painful to me. Here, I need some advice on what's the best practice in this use case? Many thanks

Comment: It seems your strategy looks good enough. In your scenario, parallelization approach is (1)"pipelined" task and (2)each "fork-joined" stage, that utilize condition variable for (1) and barrier for (2).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @yohjp. I have already implemented a working solution by applying the above approach:)

Answer (score 0):

For people who are interested in this question. I have already implemented a working solution. I think this should be typical parallel/concurrent problem as *yohjp* commented:

```
1 "Pipelined" tasks
2 "Join" on each of the stage
```

I have used an array of [num_stage] pthread barriers and an array of [num_stage+1] (pthread_cond_t, pthread_mutex_t) pairs. since in the main thread, it will use one more conditional variable to kick off.

If anyone want the sample code, please contacted me via email since it's part of one assignment work, I couldn't publish the code to github.

This is my first non-trial multi-threaded program using the raw pthread api, quite pleasant experience:)